# Using Appium how to check our app is running or closed or minimize

Tags: appium

While doing Appium testing I click on button which exit application,how to check app is running or we come back to home screen.is there any way to find element list just by package name.

Comment: Did you find any solution, would also be interested in this question. Basically I'm working currently for Android tests, and want to verify that back leaves the app.

Answer (score 5):

```
import io.appium.java_client.appmanagement.ApplicationState;
...

ApplicationState state = driver.queryAppState(bundleId)
```

`state` can one of the following based on the state.

```
NOT_INSTALLED,
NOT_RUNNING,
RUNNING_IN_BACKGROUND_SUSPENDED,
RUNNING_IN_BACKGROUND,
RUNNING_IN_FOREGROUND;
```

[References](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/c4222d80e5fe1bc53c47cba5f44bd8ec6e5d50b6/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriverTest.java#L200)

Answer (score -1):

Solution is simple, 
After you press button to exit the app, verify if any one of the elements of the app that u used still exists on the screen, if element of the app still exists then the app has not exited , if element does not exist yo can confirm that app has exited the screen.

Comment: after clicking exit button it may go to other screen of same app,so your way will say application exit,but app will be still  working,so wrong result will be displayed

Comment: Your question says if I press on button it should exit app , if it's any wr in the app , then defiantly it's a failed test case

Comment: Also u can verify the element in home screen , and confirm that it has exited the app

Comment: And how do i verify the element on the homescreen, or that the homescreen is shown?